# Valid UTF-8 string with Cyrillic symbols in C

Tags: c, json, utf-8

I try to parse an UTF-8 JSON-message in C.
I pass the following code to the parser:

```
char *text = "{\"mdl\":\"users\",\"fnc\":\"getuserslist\"}";
```

and all works. But if message has a Cyrillic characters, both of my parsers say that string is "***not valid UTF-8 string***".
Example:

```
char *text = "{\"mdl\":\"пользователи\",\"fnc\":\"получитьсписокпользователей\"}";
```

I used Jansson C parser and CCAN JSON parcer for C.
In my **main** function I have the following call of **setlocale**:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8");
```

How can I get the valid UTF-8 string using Cyrillic characters in it?

Comment: This is valid JSON, at least according to JSONLint. The library you used has a bug.

Comment: I tried this line with the two popular parsers: Jansson and CCAN JSON parcer for C.

Comment: You really should not hard-code locale names (which are not portable). Best practices would be to call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` to get the configured locale and then `assert` that `nl_langinfo(CODESET)` gives you the string `"UTF-8"` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between the source encoding (the encoding used to encode the text in the C source) and the target encoding (the encoding used to encode run-time strings) is not obvious. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551656/compiling-utf-8-encoded-source-with-unicode-line-separators) for more discussion about this.

Make sure your source encoding is UTF-8, and that the compiler is preserving this.

Or, you can manually encode your strings as UTF-8, by replacing non-ASCII characters with backslash-escaped UTF-8 sequences to be more sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to write the codes of characters like `char *text = "{\"mdl\":\" \x41 \",\"fnc\":\"getuserslist\"}";`. "\x41" (Latin 'A') works, but "\x410" (Cyrillic 'А') - **not valid**.

Comment: @Ze_ `\x410` is not UTF-8. That would be `\xd0\x90`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8"), try set console to UTF8 (cp 65001) and redirect output to file.

```
//Save As UTF-8 without BOM signature
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
int main(){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    char *text = "{\"mdl\":\"пользователи\",\"fnc\":\"получитьсписокпользователей\"}";
    printf("%s",text);
}
```

We can  get the valid UTF-8 string using Cyrillic characters:

```
{"mdl":"пользователи","fnc":"получитьсписокпользователей"}
```